# How to check current state of GPIO pin via Python?

Tags: raspberry-pi, state, gpio

I want to check state of GPIO pin when I start, a porgram. For example I have another program which changing state of pin ( if is low change to hihg, and if is high change to low). And now I want to write program what will be read current state of pin. But when I'll do this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GP
GP.setmode(GP.BOARD)
NRpin=40
GP.setup(NRpin,GP.OUT) #now GPIO state is set to default (0)
```

when I am doing

```
 GP.setup(NRpin,GP.OUT)
```

current state is replacing default state (low).

The question is: If is there any way to check current state?

I know I can do like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GP
import subprocess as sub
a=sub.check_output(['sudo', 'gpio', '-g','read','21'])
print a
```

but what if I don't have installed wiringpi on my Raspberry Pi? (gpio command is in wiringpi package).

I suppose it can look like:

```
if GP.output(NRpin,1)==True:
  print "HI"
elif GP.output(NRpin,0)==True:
  print "LO"
```

but without:

```
GP.setup(NRpin,GP.OUT)
```

I cannot use that code.

Give me some advices, prease:)

Answer (score -1):

With function  `GPIO.gpio_function(pin)` you can determine if pin is set like INPUT or OUTPUT.

To check if INPUT is HIGH or LOW, you can use `if(GPIO.input(channel)==GPIO.LOW))` or `if(GPIO.input(channel)==GPIO.HIGH))`